# Showing integral is bounded

Tags: integration

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded.
Is it true that
$$\int_A \int_A |x-y| \, dx \, dy \leq R|A|^2$$
where $R$ is some number (eg. the radius of a ball containing $A$) and $|A|$ is measure of $A$?

How do I show this rigourously?

Comment: $\lvert x-y\rvert \leqslant \operatorname{diam}(A)$ for $x,y \in A$.

Comment: Hint: try bounding $|x-y|$

Comment: What are your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is bounded, the measure $|A|$ is finite.

If you choose two points $X$ and $Y$ at random within $A$, independently of each other, the probability of either falling within any subset $B$ of $A$ being $|B|/|A|$, then the expected distance $\mathbb E|X-Y|$ is
$$
\frac{1}{|A|^2}\int_A \int_A |x-y|\,dx\,dy.
$$
Try to show that if a random variable is always within certain bounds, then so is its expected value.